# Como puedo convertir una lista y una tupla dentro de la lista en tipo float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, float, tuplas

Tengo un problema pues me gustaria convertir esto:

```
[(2,2),7]
```

En tipo float, es decir quiero que el primer numero de esa tupla sea un entero y que lo demás sea decimal y que esos numeros esten juntos. Ejemplo:

```
2.27
```

No deseo que el resultado se imprima si no se almacene en una variable y se retorne en una función

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperaría con esto `[(2, 12), 7]`? Has probado con: `resultado = x[0][0] + x[0][1]/10 +x[1]/100`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tengo una cierta obsesión por los "*one-liners*" (código en una sola línea) y como reto, se me ha ocurrido lo siguiente, que al menos para el caso que has planteado funciona perfectamente:

```
import re
a = [(2,2),7]

resultado = int("".join(re.findall(r"\d", str(a))))/100
```

Y obtienes

```
2.27
```

### Cómo funciona, y obsevaciones adicionales

Leyendo la expresión de dentro hacia afuera, lo primero que hago es convertir tu lista en una cadena con `str(a)`, lo que nos dará la cadena `"[(2, 2), 7]"`.

Esa cadena seguidamente es usada con un `re.findall()`, para encontrar todos los dígitos que haya en ella, en este caso el resultado será una lista con `["2", "2", "7"]`.

Esa lista se le pasa a `"".join()` para obtener la cadena `"227"`, que se convierte a entero con `int()` dando como resultado `227`. Finalmente se divide por 100 para sacar el flotante `2.27`.

#### Observaciones

Esta idea es bastante flexible, pues se adapta a cualquier formato de "anidación" que tengas dentro de tu lista. Por ejemplo funcionará también para las entradas `[2, 2, 7]` o `[2, (2, 7)]` o `[(2, 2, 7)]`, o `[(2,), (2,), (7,)]` etc.

Un problema es que al dividir entre 100 estamos restringiendo el uso al caso en que solo haya 3 cifras. Para hacerlo más flexible me temo que ya no se puede hacer con una sola línea, pues necesitaríamos acceder a cuántos dígitos tiene la lista que devuelve `.findall()` antes de convertirlo a entero. Esta sería una posibilidad:

```
digitos = "".join(re.findall(f"\d", str(a)))
resultado = int(digitos)/10**(len(digitos)-1)
```

Con esto ya se admitirán entradas más largas, como `[(2, 2), (7, 7), 4]` por ejemplo, que producirá 2.2774 como resultado.

Aún así tenemos una limitación: estamos suponiendo siempre que todos los elementos de la entrada son de un solo dígito (pero esta hipótesis ya estaba en tu enunciado, de forma implícita).

#### Bonus

Si estás usando Python 3.8 o superior, se puede hacer uso del operador `:=` para escribir la solución que usa dos líneas de nuevo en una sola línea, pero francamente, eso ya raya en la obsesión puesto que no se gana nada y se pierde legibilidad. No obstante, solo por curiosidad (no lo intenten en sus casas):

```
resultado = int(digitos:="".join(re.findall(f"\d", str(a))))/10**(len(digitos)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) para hacerlo

Teniendo tu lista en una variable, por ejemplo `x`:

```
x = [(2,2),7]
```

Primero unimos los elementos de la tupla con un punto intermedio, que están en el índice `0`, es decir, `x[0]`

```
x[0] = '.'.join(str(n) for n in x[0])
```

Al imprimir `x` obtendríamos:

```
['2.2', 7]
```

Luego unimos los "nuevos" elementos de `x`

```
x = ''.join(str(n) for n in x)
```

Esto nos devolvería el siguiente `string`

```
'2.27'
```

Y luego convertimos a `float`

```
x = float(x)
```

Que nos daría el número que deseas

```
2.27
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
x = [(2,2),7]
x[0] = '.'.join(str(n) for n in x[0])
x = ''.join(str(n) for n in x)
x = float(x)
print(x)
```